# Proving the inverse of an automorphism is an autumorphism

Tags: group-theory

In proving the the set $Aut(G)$ is an automorphism, we set out to prove that the automorphism forms a group under functional composition.

Closure, associativity, existence of inverse function doesn't seem to hard.

Inverse function is what I find myself having issues with.

suppose $\alpha, \beta$ is an automorphism 
$\alpha$, $\beta : G\rightarrow G$

Indeed, $\alpha$ is an automorphism implies it is bijective. The inverse of a bijective function is bijective.

To show that $\alpha$ is an automorphism, we seek to show that $\alpha$ is a an isomorphism $\alpha$:$ G\rightarrow G$
and if we can prove this, we are done.

Here is where I run into a brick wall. Referring to my notes,

it states that

> $\forall x_{1},x_{2} \in G \exists g_{1},g_{2} \in G s.t g_{1}=\left ( x_{1} \right )\alpha^{-1}$ and $g_{2}=\left ( x_{2} \right )\alpha^{-1}$ If and only If $\left ( g_{1} \right )\alpha=x_{1}$ and$ \left ( g_{2} \right )\alpha=x_{2}$

Is the above necessart to prove homomorphism?

Comment: It's a year later - out of politeness, maybe you should upvote and accept one of these answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prove that the inverse $\alpha^{-1}$ is an automorphism (apart from bijectivity) you need to establish
$$\forall y_1,y_2 \in G \quad \alpha^{-1}(y_1y_2)=\alpha^{-1}(y_1) \, \alpha^{-1}(y_2).$$
Since $\alpha$ is onto, therefore there exists $x_i \in G$ such that $\alpha(x_i)=y_i$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\alpha^{-1}(y_1y_2) & = \alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x_1) \, \alpha(x_2))\\
& = \alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x_1x_2))\\
& = x_1x_2\\
&=\alpha^{-1}(y_1) \alpha^{-1}(y_2).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The statement you ask about is true trivially because $\alpha^{-1}$ is bijective. You need to show that $\alpha^{-1}$ is a linear action on $G$. Try the following.

For all $x_1,x_2\in G$, there exist $g_1,g_2\in G$ such that $(g_1)\alpha=x_1$ and $(g_2)\alpha=x_2$. Then $$(x_1x_2)\alpha^{-1}=((x_1)\alpha(x_2)\alpha)\alpha^{-1}=((x_1x_2)\alpha)\alpha^{-1}...$$

Comment: Is this really just saying that if I can prove that the a map $\alpha$ is a homomorphism from a group G to group G, and $\alpha$ is a bijection, then the map is an automorphism? Does this make sense?

Comment: An automorphism is an isomorphism from a group to itself. An isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism, so what you are saying is really just a rewording of the *definition* of automorphism. To get that the inverse of an automorphism is an automorphism, you need to show that it is linear.